# Watermark in itextsharp is not displaying properly

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to populate the data to PDF Templates, which is created in OpenOffice. it populating fine, I'm getting proper PDF, **Watermark** is not displaying properly.

below is my code:

```
public void addWaterMark(PdfStamper stamper, int pageNumber, Watermark watermark)
    {
        List<WatermarkField> watermarkFields = watermark.getWatermarkFieldAsReference();
        for (WatermarkField watermarkField : watermarkFields) {
            // setting font and font size for the watermark text
            Font FONT = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, watermarkField.getFontSize(), Font.BOLD, new GrayColor(0.75f));
            // setting alignment for the watermark
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamper.getUnderContent(pageNumber), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(watermarkField.getText(), FONT), watermarkField.getXDirection(), watermarkField.getYDirection(), watermarkField.getRotation());
        }

    }
```

When i putting in background text-boxes are hiding the watermark.
When i putting in foreground watermark is hiding the text.
Both screen shorts are attaching below.

[image]

[image]

Please Suggest me the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect? Obviously something in the foreground covers while something in the background is covered. That been said you can reduce the amount the writing in the foreground covers by using outline writing or transparency.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351916/how-to-make-my-watermark-text-in-any-pdf-file-as-non-selectable/20361261#20361261) among other stuff contains code for using outline-only overcontent marks. It is using iText/Java but should be easy to translate for iTextSharp/C#.

Comment: mkl is correct `getUnderContent()` is the culprit. You need `getOverContent()` if you don't want the Watermark to be covered by existing content. Of course: if you don't want to cover the existing content with the watermark, you need to make it transparent as described in mkl's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351916/how-to-make-my-watermark-text-in-any-pdf-file-as-non-selectable/

Comment: @mkl here my problem is when i use `getOverContent()`, label text is covered(which is there in the Template). Strock is ok, but client is not accepting.

Comment: *client is not accepting* - what would he accept then? Transparency?

Comment: @mkl they want Transparency.. not Strocked one, they want filled one,
like first screenshot, with Transparent.

Comment: You might want to try enclosing your operation on the OverContent in `overContent.saveState(); PdfGState state = new PdfGState(); state.setFillOpacity(0.5f); overContent.setGState(state);` and `overContent.restoreState();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351916/how-to-make-my-watermark-text-in-any-pdf-file-as-non-selectable/20361261#20361261) there already are some ideas on how to add watermarks (in the under content, in the over content, both in the under content and in the over content before bitmaps.,,,).

The missing use case, a transparent mark in the over content, can be generated like this:

```
void addSimpleTransparentPatternToOverContent(File source, File target) throws IOException, DocumentException
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source.getPath());
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(target);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os);

    PdfPatternPainter painter = stamper.getOverContent(1).createPattern(200, 150);
    painter.setColorFill(BaseColor.GREEN);
    painter.beginText();
    painter.setTextMatrix(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 50));
    painter.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(), 100);
    painter.showText("Test");
    painter.endText();

    PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
    state.setFillOpacity(0.5f);

    for (int i = reader.getNumberOfPages(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(i);

        overContent.setGState(state);
        overContent.setColorFill(new PatternColor(painter));
        overContent.rectangle(200, 300, 200, 150);
        overContent.fill();
    }

    stamper.close();
    os.close();
}
```

In the spirit of that other answer the mark is generated using a pattern to prevent the watermark from appearing in copy&paste outputs.

You can change the transparency / opacity by selecting a different value in `state.setFillOpacity(0.5f)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual code.

```
public void addWaterMark(PdfStamper stamper, int pageNumber, Watermark watermark){
    List<WatermarkField> watermarkFields = watermark.getWatermarkFieldAsReference();
    PdfReader reader = stamper.getReader();
    Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(1);
    BaseFont font = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

    PdfPatternPainter painter = stamper.getOverContent(1).createPattern(pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight());
    painter.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(192, 192, 192));
    painter.setLineDash(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.2f);
    painter.beginText();
    painter.setTextMatrix(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 50));
    for (WatermarkField watermarkField : watermarkFields) {
        painter.setFontAndSize(font, watermarkField.getFontSize());
        painter.showTextAlignedKerned(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, watermarkField.getText(), watermarkField.getXDirection(), watermarkField.getYDirection(),
        watermarkField.getRotation());
    }
    painter.endText();
    PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
    state.setFillOpacity(0.2f);
    PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(pageNumber);
    overContent.setGState(state);
    overContent.setColorFill(new PatternColor(painter));
    overContent.rectangle(pageSize.getLeft(), pageSize.getBottom(), pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight());
    overContent.fill();
}
```