# How to disable selection of Watermark Text iText 7

Tags: c#, itext7

I created accessible pdf using `itext 7` and added watermark text to the pdf as below.

```
//create canvas    
canvas.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(watermarkText),x,y,textalign);
```

Watermark text gets applied to the pdf but it can be selected.

How can I disable the watermark text selection?

Comment: There is probably an answer to your question, but before I can answer, please clarify: you say that you are using iText 7, but when I look at your code, I see that you use the `ColumnText` class. The `ColumnText` class doesn't exist in iText 7; it only exists in iText 5. If I would search for the iText 7 answer, it wouldn't be helpful for you if you are, in fact, using iText 5.

Comment: Sorry I changed the code. I'm using iText 7

Comment: PDF viewers often do not allow selection of text drawn in a pattern. In this context [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20361261/1729265) is related to the topic at hand, it discusses watermark text in patterns with iText 5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can we add multiline textual watermark in a document using latest iText jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000879/can-we-add-multiline-textual-watermark-in-a-document-using-latest-itext-jar) The mechanism used there, watermark text in pattern, usually results in non-selectable text.