# can we add multiline textual watermark in a document using latest iText jar?

Tags: itext, itext7

I am looking for multi-line textual watermark feature. Does iText latest version support this feature?
I am attaching a picture of the requirement.
Let me know your findings.

[image: Multi-line Watermark]

Comment: To me that looks like a single line text applied as a pattern...

Comment: Yes, Can this feature be enabled in latest itext?

Comment: It is possible but as far as I know it requires use of the low level API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how to add repeating watermark as the background to an existing document:

```
pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inFileName), new PdfWriter(outFileName));

PdfPattern.Tiling tiling = new Tiling(new Rectangle(100, 50));
new Canvas(new PdfPatternCanvas(tiling, pdfDocument), pdfDocument, tiling.getBBox()).add(new Paragraph("TESTING")
        .setFontColor(ColorConstants.RED)
        .setRotationAngle(Math.PI / 10));

for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(i);
    new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDocument)
            .saveState()
            .setFillColor(new PatternColor(tiling))
            .rectangle(page.getCropBox())
            .fill()
            .restoreState();
}

pdfDocument.close();
```

This is how the result look visually:

[image: result]

Comment: Ok, not as low level as I thought ;) but still one needs to know one's API... The OP's image looks like the text is above content, though, 
 so he may want to use `newContentStreamAfter()` instead.

Comment: @mkl indeed, valid remark, depending on the desired result `newContentStreamAfter()` might be more suitable